# Spring path binding: is it bound directly to the variable or does it invoke the constructor/setters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring bound form (modelAttribute) which displays the user information.
The user's telephone number is displayed in a formatted manner but a requirement is that the number is saved to the database without any signs.

So in the getter method of my user object I format the telephone number according to the rules and in the setter I put the code to remove the special signs.
The formatting part works fine, but setter part where I remove the signs does not seem to occur.

In my constructor I also did:

```
setTelephoneNumber(TelephoneNumber);
```

So the constructor also invokes the setter.

I'm using Spring 3.0.4 and Spring-mvc.

Any input on this issue and how to resolve it would be appreciated.

edit:
controller section:

model.addAttribute("user", user);

JSP (shortened it a bit but this is the gist. submitUrl is due to a portal environment:

```
<form:form action="${submitUrl}" modelAttribute="user">
<form:input path="telephoneNumber"/>
</form>
```

Model telephoneNumber setter:

```
if(!StringUtils.isBlank(telephoneNumber)){
    this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
} else{
    this.telephoneNumber= "";
}
```

And I think so because the value lands in the database with the formatting I used. (spacing)

Comment: Please post the controller, the command object and the relevant part of the jsp. And how did you checked that the setter is not invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back to your question:
Spring path binding: is it bound directly to the variable or does it invoke the constructor/setters?

As fare I understand the Java Doc and some code snippets, Spring uses [BeanWrapper](http://www.javadocexamples.com/org/springframework/beans/org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapper.html) ([BeanWrapperImpl](http://www.javadocexamples.com/org/springframework/beans/org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl-source.html)) to set the values of Beans (@see [Reference: 5.4 Bean manipulation and the BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html)). And BeanWrapperImpl behaves like the reference said:
uses setter and getter to access "simple" values.

It is exactly like the reference said in section "5.4.1 Setting and getting basic and nested properties": For an expression "name":

> Indicates the property name
>   corresponding to the methods getName()
>   or isName() and setName(..)

So at least this answer your question, so I assume that the cause for your problem is some thing else.

Comment: Even if I do not like this solution (see my other answer), I have done the same thing in an old an Spring 2.0 Application, and there it workes -- the only difference was, that the setter and getter have had a different name than the field: private String telNummber vs. get/setFormatedTelNumber -- but i do not belive that this would change anyting.

Comment: Ralph, it does indeed seem like it is due the session not being clased for some reason and the object being marked as dirty.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it is not the correct answer to your question:

I strongly recommend to do the formating in an other way then by setter getter

Spring 3.0 provideds something they called "type conversion"

- [spring blog with example](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/11/17/spring-3-type-conversion-and-validation/)
- [spring reference "Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/validation.html)

Using this would be much more cleaner.

Comment: In Spring 2.x you could try to do the conversion with help of binder and property editors.

Comment: Sorry for the late response (I didn't have access to the internet yesterday). While a mask certainly is an option for a lot of things, the issue is that the formatting depends on the kind of number. Some zones have a different formatting.